# Turn off or remove x-envoy-peer-metadata

Tags: istio

Is there a way to remove x-envoy-peer-metadata or restrict the data that goes into this header? Looks like this is default behavior at egress level and it has sensitive information related to k8s and other backend components.

Comment: Looks like there are few approaches to handle this, you can check out https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/envoy-metadata-disclosure/, https://www.solo.io/blog/solving-a-real-world-information-leakage-problem-with-webassembly-and-gloo-edge/ and https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/using/headers/remove_response_headers/.

Comment: Does the above comment help anyhow?

Comment: Thank you for the comment Jakub, but we've very little info that can help me try out. So, i've taken a pause on this for now.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated, needed two files)
This is how it possible to do it via istio

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: my-namespace
  name: my-namespace-google-remove-header
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: www.google.com
      headers:
        request:
          remove:
          - x-forwarded-proto
          - x-envoy-decorator-operation
          - x-envoy-peer-metadata-id
          - x-envoy-peer-metadata
```

Then a ServiceEntry for the mesh is also needed
Below you can change port to 443 and protocol HTTPS if you need that instead

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mesh-external-www-google-com
spec:
  hosts:
    - www.google.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
  resolution: NONE
```